# Search with multiple lists

Tags: jquery

I found this great jquery plugin which filters lists.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ugWd/1/)

This filters one list `li` with one id, but I have multiple lists and I want to filter all of them when someone performs a search.

Can someone please help me with the code? Thanks heaps guys.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus for formatting the question.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs a solution :

The answer is I changed the IDs to classes and it filters all classes :)